# How can I detect if a URL is redirected to another one?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-codes, httpwebresponse, http-redirect

I use this code to make a 'GET' request to urls.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var status = response.StatusCode; // returns HttpStatusCode.OK
```

So, the probelem is when a url is redirected to another one, I can't detect it. 
For example;

```
url is: http://site.com

that redirects to http://www.site.com
```

but when I make a request to `http://site.com` it returns a `HttpStatusCode.OK` for it -instead of a redirect code. Have you any idea please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) property. Set it to false and handle the redirect yourself.

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the status code of "Redirection" instead of the "OK" and your answer is just about how to handle redirection, not to get the status code that the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HttpWebRequest.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.address.aspx) property, which is explicitly defined as "the URI after any redirections that happen during the request are complete"

Note that this should be used instead of the similar [HttpWebResponse.ResponseUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.responseuri.aspx), as its documentation says:

> Applications that need to access the last redirected ResponseUri
>   should use the [HttpWebRequest..::..Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.address.aspx) property rather than
>   ResponseUri, since the use of ResponseUri property may open security
>   vulnerabilities.